# Pass sheet to a function in vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

a function A1 is calling function A2. In A1 the excel is created and few values are populated. In the A2 function more values are populated. But it shows as error because the sheet is not defined.How to pass the sheet to a function.

Comment: Start by posting your code.  Typically if you want to pass something to a procedure you would make it an argument in the called method (A2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create excel object

```
set objExcel = CreateObject( "Excel.Application" )
```

open excel and create work book object

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("filePath")
```

create worksheet object and then you can access

```
worksheet = 1 'or your sheet number 
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet)
```

UPDATE:
You can pass your Objects into a functions, as other parameters do. here I create a function called main() and create a workbook and a worksheet then I pass workbook object in to the visibleExcel() function.

```
dim objWorkbook , objExcel
call main()
function main()
    excelPath = "D:\Development\Vbs\test.xlsx"
    set objExcel = CreateObject( "Excel.Application" )
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelPath)
    call visibleExcel(objExcel)
end function

function visibleExcel(obExcel)
    obExcel.Visible = true      
end function
```

Comment: But how to access the sheet in other function.?? Suppose i have a function A1 in which i created the worksheet object. And i'm calling a function B1 from A1 which need the sheet. How to pass the sheet to B1 in such scenario.??